# File truncated, when opened in Perl

Tags: perl, file, append, truncate

Im new to perl, so sorry if this is obvious, but i looked up how to open a file, and use the flags, but for the life of me they dont seem to work right I narrowed it down to these lines of code.

```
    if ($flag eq "T"){
        open xFile, ">" , "$lUsername\\$openFile";
    }
    else
    {
        open xFile, ">>", "$lUsername\\$openFile";
    }
```

Both of these methods seem to delete the contents of my file. I also checked if the flag is formatted correctly and it is, i know for a fact ive gone down both conditions.

EDIT: codepaste of a larger portion of my code http://codepaste.net/n52sma

Comment: The first one is supposed to delete the file.  Are you sure that the second one is also deleting the file?  Are you trying to open to read or to write?

Comment: The first one doesn't delete the file. It opens it and truncates it so you start writing at position 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New to Perl? I hope you're using [use strict](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [use warnings](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html).

As other's have stated, you should be using a test to make sure your file is open. However, that's not really the problem here. In fact, I used your code, and it seems to work fine for me. Maybe you should try printing some debugging messages to see if this is doing what you think it's doing:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;   #Will stop your program if the "open" doesn't work.

my $lUsername = "ABaker";
my $openFile  = "somefile.txt";
if ($flag eq "T") {
    print qq(DEBUG: Flag = "$flag": Deleting file "$lUsername/$openFile");
    open xFile, ">" , "$lUsername/$openFile";
}
else {
    print qq(DEBUG: Flag = "$flag": Appending file "$lUsername/$openFile");
    open xFile, ">>", "$lUsername/$openFile";
}
```

You want to use `strict` and `warnings` in order to make sure you're not having issues with variable names. The `use strict` forces you to declare your variables first. For example, are you setting `$Flag`, but then using `$flag`? Maybe `$flag` is set the first time through, but you're setting `$Flag` the second time through.

Anyway, the `DEBUG:` statements will give you a better idea of what your error could be.

By the way, in Perl, you're checking if `$flag` is set to `T` and not `t`. If you want to test against both `t` and `T`, test whether `uc $flag eq 'T'` and not just `$flag eq 'T'`.

---

#### @Ukemi

> I reformated to comply with use strict, i also made print statements to make sure i was trunctating when i want to, and not when i dont. It still is deleting the file. Although now sometimes its simply not writing, im going to give a larger portion of my code in a link, id really appreciate it if you gave it a once over.

Are you seeing it say *Truncating*, but the file is empty? Are you sure the file already existed? There's a reason why I put the flag and everything in my debug statements. The more you print, the more you know. Try the following section of code:

```
$file = "lUsername/$openFile"  #Use forward slashes vs. back slashes.
if ($flag eq "T") {
    print qq(Flag = "$flag". Truncating file "$file"\n);
    open $File , '>', $file
        or die qq(Unable to open file "$file" for writing: $!\n);
}
else {
    print qq(Flag = "$flag". Appending to file "$file"\n);
    if (not -e $file) {
        print qq(File "$file" does not exist. Will create it\n");
    }
    open $File , '>>', $file
        or die qq(Unable to open file "$file" for appending: $!\n);
}
```

- Note I'm printing out the flag and the name of the file in quotes. This will allow me to see if there are any hidden characters in my file name.
- I'm using the `qq(...)` method to quote strings, so I can use the quotation marks in my print statements.
- Also note I'm checking for the existence of the file when I truncate. This way, I make sure the file actually exists.

This should point out any possible errors in your logic. The other thing you can do is to stop your program when you finish writing out the file and verify that the file was written out as expected.

```
print "Write to file now:\n";
my $writeToFile = <>;
printf $File "$writeToFile";
close $File;
print "DEBUG: Temporary stop. Examine file\n";
<STDIN>;     #DEBUG:
```

Now, if you see it saying it's appending to the file, and the file exists, and you still see the file being overwritten, we'll know the problem lies in your actual `open xFile, ">>" $file` statement.

Comment: I reformated to comply with use strict, i also made print statements to make sure i was trunctating when i want to, and not when i dont. It still is deleting the file. Although now sometimes its simply not writing, im going to give a larger portion of my code in a link, id really appreciate it if you gave it a once over.
http://codepaste.net/n52sma

Comment: Also i know that a false conditional cant be the problem, because the append is the else statement, so anything not T should append, even if technically its not "A"

Comment: Wow its taken me so long to repost... i just got soooo busy. So your post has helped me at least find out a bit more about my program. And actually its when i read. I dont know how to read a file, using a method that creates said file, if its not made already, but if it is already made, just read. Whats happening is when i read the file, to output its contents it deletes its contents.

Comment: i ended up using Fcntl and a sysopen with O_Creat and O_EXCL flags, to make the file if it didnt exist, then open it up normally with no flags, and that is a work around for my problem. If you have a more elegant way, please tell me. Im marking this as the answer, Thank you again.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the three-argument-version of `open`, lexical filehandles and check wether there might have been an error:

```
# Writing to file (clobbering it if it exists)
open my $file , '>', $filename 
    or die "Unable to write to file '$filename': $!";

# Appending to file
open my $file , '>>', $filename 
    or die "Unable to append to file '$filename': $!";
```

Answer (score 1):

`>>` does not clobber or truncate. Either you ended up in the "then" clause when you expected to be in the "else" clause, or the problem is elsewhere.

To check what `$flag` contains:

```
use Data::Dumper;
local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
print(Dumper($flag));
```

Answer (score -3):

For your reference I have mentioned some basic file handling techniques below.

```
open FILE, "filename.txt" or die $!;
```

The command above will associate the FILE filehandle with the file filename.txt. You can use the filehandle to read from the file. If the file doesn't exist - or you cannot read it for any other reason - then the script will die with the appropriate error message stored in the $! variable.

```
open FILEHANDLE, MODE, EXPR
```

The available modes are the following:

```
read    < #this mode will read the file     
write   > # this mode will create the new file. If the file already exists it will truncate and overwrite.
append  >> #this will append the contents if the file already exists,else it will create new one.
```

if you have confusion on this, you can use the module called File::Slurp;
I have mentioned the sample codes using File::Slurp module.

```
use strict;
use File::Slurp;

my $read_mode=read_file("test.txt"); #to read file contents
write_file("test2.txt",$read_mode); #to write file
my @all_files=read_dir("/home/desktop",keep_dot_dot=>0); #read a dir
write_file("test2.txt",{append=>1},"@all_files"); #Append mode
```